# Rows add in Google Sheets v4 API - how?

Tags: java, android

I have some troubles adding rows to a spreadsheet.

In short I do the next things:

- get current records from a spreadsheet
- create a new row object
- add the newly created object to the list of current records
- call update method to update records in a spreadsheet

My update code looks like this

`UpdateValuesResponse updateResponse = this.mService.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, _range, updateValueRange);`

where `updateValueRange` is my new list of rows (of type `ValueRange`)

The question is the next.

I know that google api requires a `ValueInputOption` to be specified in the request. But what I do is a call of Google Sheets API method that doesn't require such a parameter as `ValueInputOption`.

Where should I set this `ValueInputOption`?

Thank you all for your efforts to help me!

Answer (score 4):

I have finally found the answer.

In order to set the value of `ValueInputOption` you can to use `batchUpdate()` method.

You can use it the next way:

```
BatchUpdateValuesRequest batchRequest = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
batchRequest.setValueInputOption("RAW");
batchRequest.setData(updateValueRangeList);

BatchUpdateValuesResponse updateResponse = this.mService.spreadsheets().
values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchRequest).
execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

You set it to the result of update as in:

```
this.mService.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, _range, updateValueRange).setValueInputOption("RAW");
```

hope this helps.